# Index exceeds matrix dimensions in matlab via a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I keep getting *Index exceeds matrix dimensions* every time I execute this code:

```
for i= 1:1;
    for j=1:1;
        for k=1:1;
            YC= YC(:,:,i);
            MatrixM= M(:,:,:,j);
            Graphmenow= GraphMe(:,:,k);
        end
    end
end 

FinalOutput= [MatrixM];
AYesIdiditNow2=[FinalOutput];
AGraphFinale= Graphmenow;
```

Comment: You did not even ask a question here. As for the question: where is `i`? It's not in your loop. And fairly simple: you're probably calling an N-dimensional matrix with too many dimensions.

Comment: @Adriaan - It is.... just the code formatting sucked.  I fixed it.

Comment: You are getting that error because either `YC` is not a 3D matrix, `M` is not a 4D matrix or `Graphme` is not a 3D matrix.  Please go into your command prompt, and type in `size(YC), size(M)` and `size(Graphme)`.  You should see that they're a 3D, 4D and 3D matrix respectively for this code to work.  If they're not, then that's why it isn't working.  Also, bear in mind that `YC` **changes** when the loop finishes, so when it used to be a 3D matrix, it's now a 2D matrix.